# AWK to look for common data in two column in same file

Tags: awk

I am using below code/command to look for common data in two file and sending output in some file if found.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{l[$0]=NR; next}; $0 in l{print $0, l[$0], FNR}' MF*.txt OF*.txt > F22.txt`enter code here`
```

But i need your help here By using AWK, i need to look for common data in two column in same file only
For example below are two columns with data, and need to search if column ***A*** is equal to the word ***CAN*** then if column ***B*** contains some value found in column ***C*** and would then like to print these matches into separate file with line number and any error code.

```
A       B           C
CAN     9876        45678
CAN     1234        93939
CAN     45678       9090
ABC     4567        8080
BCD     97654       9876
CAN     9090        8181
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: With globbing ie `MF*.txt OF*.txt` things might not work in the fashion you expect. You may be looking for comparing `MF1.txt` against `OF1.txt` and so. Aren't you?

Comment: @sjsam you are everywhere :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR>1{if($1=="CAN"){lines[$2]=NR" "$0;}C[$3]=$3}END{for(i in lines){if(C[i])print lines[i]}}' input_file.txt > output_file.out
```

to identify the lines that meet the condition described in your question:

> need to search if column A is equal to the word CAN then if column B
>   contains some value found in column C and would then like to print
>   these matches into separate file with line number and any error code.

**output with your input data:**

```
7 CAN     9090        8181
2 CAN     9876        45678
4 CAN     45678       9090
```

**Explanations:**

- `NR>1` to start the processing from the second line
- `if($1=="CAN"){lines[$2]=NR" "$0;}` for each line that starts with `CAN` you store the line with its line number in an array for which the key/index is the value of the 2nd column.
- `C[$3]=$3` stores all the values of the 3rd column
- `END{for(i in lines){if(C[i])print lines[i]}` checks for all lines stored if there exists a value in the 3rd column that is equal to the value of the 2nd column if it is the case it outputs the line number and the line in question.

  If you are **several input files** to process you can use the following `awk` 
  command:

  ```
  awk 'FNR>1{if($1=="CAN"){lines[$2]=FILENAME" "FNR" "$0;}C[$3]=$3}END{for(i in lines){if(C[i])print lines[i]}}' MF*.txt OF*.txt > output_file.out
  ```

where

- `FNR` is the relative position in each file
- `FILENAME` is the name of the current file being processed
- **Hypothesis**: each file first line is header `A B C` if it is not the case you can remove `FNR>1`

**TEST:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan,
Thanks a ton.
Your solution solved my query

Comment: good it helped you! I will give you an updated version for numerous input files if you need it

Comment: yes sure..it would be helpful..definitely i will get something to learn from it...

Comment: Thank you once again Allan..
i find it very useful